# why having try/catch in corutineAScope block still crash by the exception caught

Tags: exception, kotlin-coroutines

```
  fun main() = runBlocking {
        coroutineScope {

            val child = async {
                Log.e("+++", "+++  in  async{}, throw exception , ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                throw Exception("test exception with await() in async")
            }

            try {
                child.await()
            } catch(ex: Throwable) {
                Log.e("+++", "+++  child.await() caught  exception $ex, ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            }

        }
  }
```

The log `"+++  child.await() caught  exception java.lang.Exception: test exception with await() in aync, main"` . shows the exception is caught,  but it still crashes the app.

Why the expiation caught is still crashing the app with coroutines?

Comment: Exception("test exception with await() in async")

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of [`coroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html):

> This function is designed for parallel decomposition of work. When any child coroutine in this scope fails, this scope fails and all the rest of the children are cancelled (for a different behavior see supervisorScope). This function returns as soon as the given block and all its children coroutines are completed.

Remove the `coroutineScope` and it should function as you are expecting it should.

Comment: thanks @kiskae!  I guess it does not tell why the try/catch does not prevent the crash with the coroutineScope.

Comment: Because `async` is a child of the `coroutineScope` and it failed. Regardless of what other code in the scope does the exception handler will cause the outer scope to fail as per the documentation. You could work around it by assigning a `ExceptionHandler` to the `async` block and swallowing the exception there instead.

Comment: I did not realize what the `fail` means in the the "Regardless of what other code in the scope does the exception handler will cause the outer scope to fail."  It is different with coroutines  that in some case the try/catch doesnt prevent the crash as it is used to.

Answer (score 1):

[find this is helpful as well](https://edit.theappbusiness.com/kotlin-coroutines-in-android-part-6-483ed521374), and [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/763):

```
whenever a coroutine created by async() throws an exception, 
the same exception is thrown both by its Deferred.await() 
and inside the body of the parent coroutine as well! 
This means that, no matter if we catch the exception by surrounding await() with try/catch, 
our app is still going to crash because the exception is not thrown just 
from the await() suspension point
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception thrown by the child coroutine bubbles up to its immediate parent. You must try catching exceptions in parent coroutines. This way application won't crash.